# XML file stores image location then use SimpleXML

Tags: php

I just want to know if i'm doing this right. I put a markup for the image location in my xml file. I read it using this statement for php.

```
foreach($xml->children() as $image)
{
echo "<img src=\"$image->image\"/>";
}
```

Is this fine?

Comment: if it works, i see nothing criminal

Comment: please include example of the xml

Comment: It works. I'm just asking if it's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your xml file is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

    <image>a.jpg</image>
    <image>b.jpg </image>
    <image>c.jpg </image>
    <image>d.jpg </image>
```

you can use this code

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");



foreach($image->children() as $image)
{
    echo "<img src=\"$image->image\"/>";
}

?>
```